# Marshaling double array from C# to JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, com, marshalling

In my WPF app I have a `WebBrowser` control, which hosts some HTML5/javaScript content. 
With `webBrowser.ObjectForScripting` I'm passing special object with argument to that script.
Everything was fine until I tried to pass a simple 1D array of double values. I've tried a lot of ways, starting from simple public field with that array, finishing with complex methods like

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("1F436D05-1111-3340-8050-E70166C7FC86")]
public class ScriptObject
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public double[] d = { 1,2,3 };

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public object Data { get { return d; } set { d = value; } }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_ARRAY)]
    public object GetArr()
    {
        return d;
    }
}
```

but nothing seems to work. I'm regulary get exceptions from javaScript code inside `webBrowser` control such as "expexted string" or something like this when trying to access array via
`window.external.GetArr()` or `window.external.Data`.

If I'm not mistaking with documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc645074(v=vs.95).aspx), there should be a proper way to do this, but how?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try accessing the array in JavaScript this way: `var arr = new VBArray(window.external.Data).toArray();`. JavaScript cannot natively consume safearrays, only via `VBArray` wrapper. Also, I'm pretty sure you need `SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_R8` annotation, not `VT_ARRAY`; you need to describe the type of the array elements.

Comment: Thank you! That really helped. The only one question here is that it would be better to have double[] array passed to JS instead of object[] but when changing that way, VBArray in JavaScript is not constructed. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: VBArray can consume a safearray of doubles, when explicitly constructed using Windows API. The problem is likely on C#-to-COM side of things, which I'm completely unfamiliar with. COM-to-JavaScript side of things should work, for what it's worth.